# Dockerize multipaged react app (error: 404 Not Found nginx/1.21.4)

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx

I've written a react app with a banch of different urls using  component and I'm trying to deploy it using docker. While the main page loads the rest of them don't. When I run npm run build everything works fine so the problem is probably in my Dockerfile. The error I get is 404 Not Found nginx/1.21.4

```
# build environment
FROM node:14.18.1 as build
WORKDIR /app
# ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
#COPY package.json /app/package.json
#RUN npm install --silent
#RUN npm install react-scripts@3.0.1 -g --silent
#COPY . /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:1.21.4-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "nginx","-g", "daemon off;"]
```

The comments are my previous attemps thet didn't work
package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.4.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.2.17",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.8",
    "postcss": "^7.0.39",
    "postcss-cli": "^9.1.0",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17"
  }
}
```

nginx.config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your package.json file so we can see what your npm commands do. Also it'd be nice to know which request you're getting the 404 on. Since the main page loads, it's not all requests, right?

Comment: I get the error in any url that haw the form localhost/<text> the only url that works is /localhost

Answer (score -3, accepted):

My Dockerfile was wrong the correct one is:

```
# build environment
FROM node:14.18.1 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY . .
RUN npm ci
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:1.21.4-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /app/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "nginx","-g", "daemon off;"]
```